# Measure a length of a line segment in pixels from an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I have a ton of images like the one shown below. I am trying to detect nanoparticles from transmission electron microscopy images which I have successfully achieved using OpenCV-Python. The image is just a crop of the bottom left corner of a bigger transmission electron microscopy image. I would like to extract the length of the white colored line segment under the '100 nm'. Currently, I am manually measuring the length of this line and I would like to automate this. I think this could be done with OpenCV-Python by contouring, but I have lot of other features which are also contoured in the image.  I am new to Python and I am not very sure on how to implement this or if this can be implemented at all. My idea about what the code should do:

1. Load the image
2. Find the white line segment
3. Return it's length in pixels.
4. It would also be nice, if it detects what the number just above the line and returns it too.

Any suggestions, directions or 'where to start' comments are greatly welcome and appreciated.

The line is segment is very unique in its features and there is only one line in every image.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can binarize your image to find contour of the scale segment:

[image: processing]

```py
scale = cv2.imread('scalenanometer.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
scale_gray = cv2.cvtColor(scale, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# adjust the second value of the next line to tune the detection
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(scale_gray, 210, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# filter noisy detection
contours = [c for c in contours if cv2.contourArea(c) > 100]
# sort from by (y, x)
contours.sort(key=lambda c: (cv2.boundingRect(c)[1], cv2.boundingRect(c)[0]))
# work on the segment
cv2.rectangle(scale, cv2.boundingRect(contours[-1]), (0,255,0), 2)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[-1])
print(x,y,w,h) # x,y: (39 152) w,h: [304 21]
```

If you want to detect the value, you can use tesseract ocr.

Comment: So, I should crop the bigger image  every time in order to avoid other contours.  I will look into tesseract ocr. Thanks for this. I will try this and update.

Comment: It is better to crop to avoid noisy/fake detection, and with this method, it is not based on average, so you always should have the same result except if you change the threshold value

Comment: Worked Quite well, also a very accurate width measurement (I compared with another measurement tool) Thanks a lot! Just wanted to know what exactly is the sort function doing? . I understand there would be multiple contours. So by sorting you select the largest rectangle?

Comment: @Worriedandwaiting, the sort line is to sort by `(y,x)` because `findContours()` also detect the `100 nm` contours, so by sorting first `y` and then `x` you are sur that the last contour is always the segment

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is using the probabilistic Hough line method for detecting the line.

The result will be:

[image]

Now the problem is multiple lines are detected. We know their coordinates. If we print them all:

```
Pixel Length: 296
Pixel Length: 197
Pixel Length: 308
Pixel Length: 175
Pixel Length: 292
Pixel Length: 229
Pixel Length: 103
Pixel Length: 109
```

Since there are a lot of lengths detected, maybe finding its average is meaningful:

```
Average Pixel Length: 109 pixel
```

Though I'm not sure how to convert 109 pixel to 100nm.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("4HQtp.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 150, apertureSize=3)
base = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 80, minLineLength=1, maxLineGap=6)
pixel_array = []
pixel_length = 0
if base is not None:
    for line in base:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
        cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        pixel_length = np.abs(x2 - x1)
        pixel_array.append(pixel_length)
        print("Pixel Length: {}".format(pixel_length))
    cv2.imshow("img", img)
    cv2.imwrite("hough_img.png", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
print("Average Pixel Length: {:.0f} pixel".format(np.average(pixel_array)))
```

Comment: Hi, the white line is equal to 100 nm. I just needed the the size in pixels as I need to measure other objects in the image, using this scale. I will try this and get back to you.

Comment: This approach is not enough efficient because HoughLine detect a lot a "little" line with size like `[197, 175, 103]` which is obviously a small part of the wanted segment. So your final average is completly wrong

Comment: @Ahmet, your average is 213, and the segment size is greater than 300... How do you call that ?

Comment: Where 213?  `Average Pixel Length: 109 pixel`

Comment: First: 109 is worst, Second: How can you have 109 as average with the values that you give ? You have a mistake in your code to calculate your average... You calculate your average with just 1 value and not a list of value, so your average is always the last value...

Comment: Unfortunately, in some images, It detected a lot of lines and taking the average in this scenario seemed incorrect. Thanks a lot for your suggestion!

Comment: Well, that's how HoughLines algorithm works. It was the first idea that come to my mind. Guess you have to play with parameters to get an accurate result. Besides I have to tell 109 worst for what? what comparison? just to win an internet discussion people are just talking.

Comment: @Ahmet, Are you serious, you can't see the problem ? When you have values like `[296, 197, 308, 175...]` how can you have an average of `109` just look at your mistake